# Can I provide a value in custom-values.yaml file which is not there in default values.yaml file in HELM

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I was wondering whether I can provide a value in custom-value.yaml file in helm which is not there in the default values.yaml file or am I restricted to pass only the overrides. I could not find this information anywhere in the docs.
Though I did a dry run with one of the charts and the COMPUTED VALUES showed me the variable which I seeded from my custom-values.yaml file and which was not there in the default values.yaml file.
So it seems like we can pass anything in the custom-values.yaml file and not just the overrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass anything you want via `helm install -f` or `helm install --set` options; it doesn't specifically have to be something listed in the `values.yaml` file.

The reverse of this is that setting a value doesn't do anything unless the chart is specifically looking for it.  For most public charts, there aren't undocumented values, and every possible setting is at least mentioned in the `values.yaml` file.